# MVC Decision making on _Layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control

So I have had a look around and I cannot seem to find a suitable solution to my problem.

**Problem**

In my layout I want to be able to choose if a nav item is present at runtime depending on what is in the database:

**Current layout (Navbar)**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Index", "Dashboard")</li>
           <li>@Html.ActionLink("NzbGet", "Index", "NzbGet")</li>
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("Plex", "Index", "Plex")</li>
              <li>@Html.ActionLink("Settings", "Index", "Settings")</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
```

How I am able to make decisions to see which one to show:

```
public PrincipleExtension(ISettingsService<SabNzbSettingsDto> sab)
{
    SabService = sab;
}

private ISettingsService<SabNzbSettingsDto> SabService { get; set; }    
public bool IsApplicationEnabled(IPrincipal principal, Applications application)
{
    switch (application)
    {
        case Applications.SabNZBD:
            return SabService.GetSettings().Enabled;
            //...
     }
     return false;
 }
```

Now the `PrincipleExtension` was originally an extension method on `IPrincipal`. But that is now not possible as I am using an IoC container and do not want to hard code any dependencies.

So before when it was a static method I could have done `User.IsApplicationEnabled(Applications.SabNZBD)`.

How am I able to check if an application has the enabled flag set to true in the layout now? Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried sending the flag through ViewBag?

Comment: @MarianEne that would mean that the ViewBag property would need to be present on every request (since it's on the Layout). That sounds dirty (and not in the good way).

Comment: Yes you're right. I haven't thought that through very well.

Comment: While I know [this](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/19/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-views/) great arcticle is a bit off date, but I would suggest you to take a look at it for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your menu HTML to a PartialView and have it return as an ActionResult from a Controller Action.

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li><a href="@item.Url">@item.Name</a></li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

Have the controller determine which menu items are to be present and send the new model off to the PartialView.

```
public ActionResult ProductsMenu()
{
    var listOfAvailableProducts = GetAvialableProducts(Principal); //to implement elsewhere
    var productsMenuItems = new List<ProductMenuItem>();

    for(var i in listOfAvailableProducts)
    {
        productsMenuItems.Add(new ProductMenuItem
            {
                Id = i.id,
                Name = i.name,
                Url = "//example.com/there"
            }
        );
    }

    return PartialView("/path/to/_ProductsMenu.cshtml", productsMenuItems);
}
```

Then call it in _Layout.cshtml razor view like this:

`@{
    Html.RenderAction("ActionName","ControllerName");
}`

Comment: I think this is probably the best option.This way I can use an in memory cache and also `[OutputCache]`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at the nuget package titled MVCSitemapProvider.

It comes with bootstrap interoperability and you can use it to dynamically generate your navigation at runtime giving you full flexibility to check the state/status of your navigation at any given time.

https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider

This link shows that you can dynamically generate your navigation nodes at any time:

```
public class StoreDetailsDynamicNodeProvider 
: DynamicNodeProviderBase 
{ 
public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node) 
{
    using (var storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities())
    {
        // Create a node for each album 
        foreach (var album in storeDB.Albums.Include("Genre")) 
        { 
            DynamicNode dynamicNode = new DynamicNode(); 
            dynamicNode.Title = album.Title; 
            dynamicNode.ParentKey = "Genre_" + album.Genre.Name; 
            dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("id", album.AlbumId);

            yield return dynamicNode;
        }
    }
} 
}
```

Another benefit to this approach is that it brings back the Sitemap.xml-esque functionality allowing you to assign static and dynamic navigation simultaneously.

Here's an example of my menu displaytemplate:

```
@model MenuHelperModel

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top hidden-print">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navContainer">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a href="~/" class="navbar-brand">AH Operations&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navContainer">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
            @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes)
{
    if (node.Title == "Separator")
    {
                <li class="nav-divider"></li>
    }
    else if (node.Children.Any())
    {
        if (node.IsCurrentNode || node.IsInCurrentPath)
        {
                <li class="active dropdown">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)
                </li>
        }
        else
        {
                <li class="dropdown">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node)
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)
                </li>
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (node.IsCurrentNode || node.IsInCurrentPath)
        {
                <li class="active">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node)
                </li>
        }
        else
        {
                <li>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(m => node)
                </li>
        }
    }
}
        </ul>
        @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
    </div>
</div>
```

To get it to work with the infinite n+1 sub-menu style that was removed in Bootstrap 3, add this CSS:

```
.navbar-user {
font-size: 14px !important;
}

.dropdown-submenu {
position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -6px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
    border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
    border-left-color: #cccccc;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
    border-left-color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
    float: none;
}

    .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
        left: -100%;
        margin-left: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
        border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure how this helps me, can you tailor the answer to my question please.

Comment: I'm not going to write your code for you, but if you use the code above for generating the dynamic node collection and use it to populate your menu, you could theoretically use that same method to get a complete list of your entire navigation, iterate through it and match it with whatever you wanted to confirm whether or not it's present.

Comment: I never asked you to 'write the code for me'. You have just copied and pasted your code. All I was asking was to tailor it to my question, remove all of the unnecessary code.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood.


Step 1: Install MVCSiteMapProvider 5 (Where 5 is whatever version of MVC you're using)
Step 2: Code a method similar to above to populate a dynamicnode object with your menu items (This will allow you to populate your menu from the db possibly eliminating your need for the check)
Step 3: Wherever you need to do the check to see if the menu item exists, call the method from step 2, iterate through it and match as necessary

Comment: As for the code that i should remove . . technically all of it is needed. The first bit of code is for generating the menu items dynamically at runtime. The second bit is a cleaned up implementation of a displaytemplate that gets included with MVCSitemapProvider for generating/rendering the menu and the last CSS is used for fixing a flaw with boostrap for a feature that they removed so it re-adds the ability to have an unlimited number of nested submenus

Comment: And how do you pass the Nodes to the view?

Comment: @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false) (It uses display templates and HtmlExtension methods similarly to @Html.DisplayFor(d => d.Property)). The documentation from the link i provided should give you implementation examples

Answer (score 0):

I would create a global ActionFilter and override the OnActionExecuting method to place your flag in the ViewBag for every request.  You could also create an HtmlHelper extension method.

Comment: Again. Having a property in the ViewBag in my opinion is not ideal, seems more like a hack rather than a solution. Also having to execute the code to check it on every request would cause a lot of DB traffic.